# Retrieve Framework List

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plugins, frameworks

I'd like to know if it is possible to get a list of the frameworks being used in an Objective-C project.

Perhaps there's some way to access XCode's "Build Phases"? Doesn't matter if it's some obscure method not advised by Apple, I'm trying to make an XCode plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't written a Xcode plugin (yet), but is there a way for you to use terminal commands? If this is possible you could open the projects build path and simply use

```
ls *.framework
```

They should also be linked in the **.xcodeproj** file.

Comment: It didn't work. The target's buildpath is its folder inside "DerivedData", but there's no .framework objects there.

I've also tried to check the contents of the .xcodeproj and .xcworkspace objects but there was also nothing.